# Visual Studio 2015 files in multiple folders

Tags: visual-studio, file, path

I'm new to Visual Studio and I have a problem with my project files. My project is saved in a different folder than my "Form1" files. Like Form1.resx, Form1.cs and Form1.Designer.cs. How do i get all these files in the same folder without ruining my program? I need to export my project to another person, so I can't do that now.

Any solutions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To export a project (solution?) to another person, you should zip the entire root folder of that solution, optionally removing output folders (bin, obj).